# how to provide a second model form into first model form if the data entered correct in first model form in django admin?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

I have a very complex situation.

```
from types import *
from django import forms
from django.db.models import Q
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from schdeules.models import tbmsttemplate,tbmstreviewsched,tbtrnrevdepartments,tbtrnrevdesignations,tbmstappraisalsched,tbtrnappraisalreview,tbmstdepartment,tbmstpart,tbmstsection,tbtrnappraisalquestion
class tbmstappraisalschedForm(forms.ModelForm):
  def clean(self):
      """ 
      Override the default clean method to check whether this course has been already inputted.
      """    
      cleaned_data = super(tbmstappraisalschedForm, self).clean()

      depart_id = self.cleaned_data.get('intDeptID')
      fromdate = str(self.cleaned_data.get('sdtFromDate'))
      todate = str(self.cleaned_data.get('sdtToDate'))
      pk=self.instance.pk

      res = tbmstappraisalsched.objects.filter( 
      Q(sdtFromDate__lte=fromdate,sdtToDate__gte=fromdate) |  \
      Q(sdtFromDate__lte=todate,sdtToDate__gte=todate), ~Q(intAppSchedID=pk),
      intDeptID=depart_id.pk,
      )
      if(res).exists():
        raise ValidationError('The slot is present for selected dates and selected department')

      else:
        res_revs = tbmstreviewsched.objects.filter( 
        Q(sdtFromDate__lte=fromdate,sdtToDate__gte=fromdate) |  \
        Q(sdtFromDate__lte=todate,sdtToDate__gte=todate),     
        tbtrnrevdepartments__intDeptID=depart_id.pk,
        )
        if(res_revs).exists():
           show review scheds such that user can select needed review scheds and save data in two models at once i.e; tbmstappraisalsched,tbtrnappraisalreview
           return self.cleaned_data 
        else: 
            raise ValidationError('Reviewschedule slots are not present for the selected dates and selected department')


class Meta:
    model = tbmstappraisalsched
```

in above code i have to get review scheds from tbmstreviewsched and show to user such that he can select required review sched and save the data in two models at once in such a way the data has to be saved in tbmstappraisalsched which returns intappschedid(autoincrement value) and then the data has to be saved in tbtrnappraisalreview with new intappschedid and selected review sched ids. 
and my admin.py code is

```
from schdeules.models import  tbmsttemplate,tbmstreviewsched,tbtrnrevdepartments,tbtrnrevdesignations,tbmstappraisalsched,tbtrnappraisalreview,tbmstpart,tbmstsection,tbtrnappraisalquestion
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from forms import tbmstappraisalschedForm

class QuestionsInline(admin.StackedInline):
 model = tbtrnappraisalquestion
 extra = 0
class TemplatesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

 readonly_fields = ("intUpdatedBy",)
 inlines = [QuestionsInline]

 def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    obj.intUpdatedBy = request.user.id
    obj.save()
class ReviewDesignationInline(admin.StackedInline):
 model = tbtrnrevdesignations
 extra = 1
class ReviewDepartmentInline(admin.StackedInline):
 model = tbtrnrevdepartments
 exclude = ['intUpdatedBy']
 extra = 1
class ReviewScheduleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
 inlines = [ReviewDepartmentInline,ReviewDesignationInline]
 exclude = ['intUpdatedBy']
 def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    obj.intUpdatedBy = request.user.id
    obj.save()
class AppraisalScheduleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
 exclude = ['intUpdatedBy']
 form = tbmstappraisalschedForm
 def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    obj.intUpdatedBy = request.user.id
    obj.save()
class AppraisalReviewAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
 exclude = ['intUpdatedBy']
 def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    obj.intUpdatedBy = request.user.id
    obj.save()

admin.site.register(tbmstpart)
admin.site.register(tbmstsection)
admin.site.register(tbmsttemplate,TemplatesAdmin)
admin.site.register(tbmstreviewsched,ReviewScheduleAdmin)
admin.site.register(tbmstappraisalsched,AppraisalScheduleAdmin)
admin.site.register(tbtrnappraisalreview,AppraisalReviewAdmin)
```

Comment: So what's your question? Your title is talking about django admin but you haven't provided any `admin.py` code.

Comment: I have provided admin.py file code